# jquery scrollTO iPhone/iPad doesn't scroll right

Tags: javascript, iphone, scrollto

I have problem with scrollTO jquery pluging when the page is viewed on iPhone or Ipad.
When clicked on on of the buttons the scrolling refresh the page and then scroll, it looks like the page flickers while scrolling.
All I want is to have smoothly scrooling to exact element on the page.

You can find developemnet version of the Page [here](http://preview.forwardandforward.com/cloudit/).

Can someone please help me ho to solve this problem?

Thank you and regards, Matej.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if it's a bug in the script or in your webpage.

Create a simple website with just the scroller plugin and add some scroll anchors. 
If it flickers on iOS too it's a bug in the script, otherwise something is your websites code causes this bug.

Another options my be to pick another scroller plugin. Guess there are more than one.